# Android: Compound Drawables With Intrinsic Bounds on 4.2.2 and below

Tags: android, checkbox, android-4.2-jelly-bean, compound-drawables

I try to use checkbox with left Compound Drawable like this:

```
holder.selCategoryCheckBox.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imageResource, 0, 0, 0);
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/category_sel_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/categorySelectionOptions"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/categorySelectionOptions"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/more_than_big_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/big_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/big_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/big_padding"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/five_margin"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categorySelectionOptions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_middle_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/main_middle_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector_list_dots"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_drawer_dots"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

On Android 4.3 Jelly Bean and Up is working fine:
[image]

But On Android 4.2 Jelly Bean and below the spacing is broken:
[image]

Some ideas, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary workaround:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_sel_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/larger_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/larger_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_sel_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/middle_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/middle_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/large_margin"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/category_sel_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/five_margin"/>
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categorySelectionOptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_middle_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/main_middle_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/row_selector_list_dots"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_drawer_dots"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
</FrameLayout>
```